# Open CMD as admin with Windows+R shortcut

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, administrator

My preference for running CMD is to use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> » type `cmd` » <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But this doesn't open it with admin rights. Is there a way to type your way through to command prompt with admin rights?

Comment: Which version of Windows? You can start an admin command prompt from `Win+x` "Power User Menu" in recent versions.

Comment: You could type `runas /user:Administrator cmd`

Comment: @RJFalconer This is valid. Please post it as an answer

Comment: Also check out my [`wsudo`](https://github.com/noseratio/choco/tree/master/wsudo), a `sudo`-like tool for Windows available as a Chocolatey package.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The easiest and quickest solution that follows your method, is by starting the command prompt as follows:

Press <kbd>win</kbd> to open the start menu. Type in `cmd` to search for Command Prompt.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to launch Command Prompt as administrator.

This works from Windows 7 and up.

win+r does not natively support this though, but an alternative (and less quick) way, is to type in `runas /user:Administrator cmd` and then type the password for the administrator account.

EDIT: It seems that the latest version of Windows 10 does offer support for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> at the Win+R dialog, so you can now use it there too.

Comment: The first option is pretty quick! the second one is eventually even faster if  `Win` + `R` keeps the command ;)

Comment: Note that `ctrl+shift+enter` works on any shortcut found in Start menu. If it is a real program it will fail to elevate to Admin

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` works even in the Win+R prompt

Comment: @phuclv Microsoft must have changed this behavior then. It was not possible to do this earlier. Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the answer.

Comment: actually that shortcut has existed [since Vista](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tims/2006/11/02/windows-vista-secret-10-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-in-six-keystrokes/). However in my experience it doesn't work reliably on all PCs although I don't know the real reason

Comment: Press Windows Key + X then press A to open a CMD.exe with admin rights.

Comment: @Rahul newer versions of Windows 10 will replace CMD with Powershell. when that happens, your suggestion will open Powershell as CMD. Although it would still work, not everyone is comfortable with that.

Comment: @LPChip What will be the option when Administrator account is disabled. Account with administrator privilege can't run program (i.e. the program needs to run as administrator)

Comment: @maruf the quickest way is to just type your command, and instead of pressing enter or clicking okay, hold ctrl-shift too. So for example type cmd, then ctrl-shift-enter.

Answer (score 33):

Another fast way is to use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then hit <kbd>A</kbd>.

However I marked the other answer as the correct one because the question originally asked for a way to do that through <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Nice answer. It does however only apply to Windows 8 and higher., which is something you did not specify in your question. Win+R is available in all OS's including Windows XP even. Because Windows XP is long dead, I carefully assumed you'd be at least on windows 7 by now.

Comment: Just a heads-up, this does not work on the latest Windows 10 anymore, given that Microsoft has replaced Command Prompt with Powershell.

Comment: Voting this as you can still use this in Windows 10, by going to Settings>Taskbar>[Replace Command Prompt with Windows Powershell ..] -- turn this off.

Comment: Perhaps this is the coolest thing of day. I wish somehow I can bypass run as admin prompt by windows. I have to click on yes every time

Comment: Thanks - wish they also had regular command prompt as admin as an option but this is a really good tip. I hated opening the run command.

Answer (score 4):

**a simple answer:**

1. create a shortcut (LNK) to cmd.exe
2. right-click the shortcut > properties > advanced > [v] run as administratir
3. move the shortcut to a directory on the PATH

now: Win+R > admin > simply hit ok or enter.

**nice to have**

1. UAC auto-click.  it's possible, but WAY out of this scope (and a security break), so I'll press manually Alt+y.
2. system-wide keyboard shortcut that links to this shortcut (or alternative command) directly. I'm using Win+Alt+C

**alternative (external) commands**

```
elevate.exe cmd
nircmdc.exe elevatecmd
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c %CD% && %1 %2 %3 %4 %5' -Verb runas"
```

(Tested on windows 7)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10, you can also type cmd in Run window, press Shift + Ctrl + Enter, instead of just pressing just enter. It will ask for permission & cmd will be in Administrator mode.

Comment: @phuclv Accepted answer is telling to search command prompt in Start menu. My answer is useful in the case where start menu doesn't open.

Comment: no. In any Windows, not only Windows 10, pressing Win+R, type command > Ctrl+Shift+Enter works. And in Windows 10 it's better to use Win+X > A

Comment: @phuclv Dude, instead of telling in comments, add your own answer.

Comment: no. this should be an answer to the other answer

Answer (score 3):

To run cmd as administrator through Win+R without additional password typing (but UAC warning is still in-place though) just use the following trick:

```
powershell "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
```

If you want to get an access to cmd by clicking a shortcut:

1. Create a shortcut for cmd (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe)
2. Right-click the shortcut > Properties
3. Find "Target" field on "Shortcut" tab
4. Replace the target value with
   `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C powershell "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

1. Right click task bar
2. Open ***Task Manager***
3. Click **More details** option (it will show the menu bar)
4. Click ***File -> Run new task***
5. Enter ***cmd*** and select ***Create this task with administrative privileges*** check box

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me (W10):

1- Pin the **taskmanager** In Taskbar : **C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> , richt click on the **taskmanager** in the **taskbar**  and select "**Pin to taskbar**" and close the **taskmanager**.

2- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the pinned **taskmanager**

3- Type the administrator and password account

4- Click on **File** -> **Run new task**

6- Enter "**cmd**" and select "**Create this task with administrative privileges.**" check box

Let the Taskmanager open If you need to use other commands with admin rights by using the check box (regedit.exe, services.msc, mmc.exe, control userpasswords2...)

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 10 [Build 16362](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-command-elevated-administrator-ctrl-shift-enter-windows-10/) (and higher), you can use the `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`  shortcut in the Run dialog to launch a program elevated.