# Windows Explorer Navigation Pane - Manual reordering

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I really want `This PC` to be the first element in my navigation pane, after `Quick access`, but things like `OneDrive` and `Dropbox` give themselves higher priority:

[image]

How can I reorder or remove specific entries?

Answer (score 15):

<sup>On Windows 10...</sup>

I have only found the Navigation Pane to be configurable directly in the [Windows Registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-open-registry-editor-in-windows-10-deab38e6-91d6-e0aa-4b7c-8878d9e07b11), without using a third-party tool.

3rd-party entries are under the path `\HKEY_USERS\[*SID*]_Classes\CLSID\[*ApplicationHash*]`. If you're the only user logged on, your [SID](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-an-sid-number-2626005) (or Security Identifier) will be obvious because there will only be one. **It is the long one.** Entries only exist for users currently logged in, otherwise you can [determine your SID](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-find-a-users-security-identifier-sid-in-windows-2625149) by using the Command Prompt statement `wmic useraccount get name,sid`.

Entries can be found by searching for the name that shows in the Navigation Pane. The ones listed in the question are as follows:

1. `{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-xxxxxxxxxxxx}` OneDrive
2. `{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-xxxxxxxxxxxx}` Creative Cloud Files
3. `{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-xxxxxxxxxxxx}` Dropbox

Note that different people may have a varying value for the last 12-digit segment in the path.

---

Entries are configured using the two values `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` (boolean) and `SortOrderIndex` (integer) which control visibility and the order *ranking*, respectively:

[image]

**Reorder** the entries by updating all the `SortOrderIndex` values (ignoring those you disable, of course), with new values such that sorting those smallest to largest would be in the same order you want the Navigation Pane entries<sup>3</sup>.

For example, to reorder such that *This PC* comes before *DropBox* and then *OneDrive*, you could set `SortOrder` of *DropBox* to 998 and *OneDrive* to 999.

Once you have specified your configuration, force restart Windows Explorer to effect the update by killing it with Task Manager (open directly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and re-launching from there (`File > Run new task > explorer.exe`).

---

***Quick Access*** can be removed by adding a new REG_DWORD `HubMode` with value `1` to the path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`. [More info](https://superuser.com/a/1409261/207006).

---

Notes

1. You will have to repeat these steps when applications update. Permissions can only be set on the keys (i.e. folders), not the individual values to prevent them from being modified, and denying access to a key has the same effect as setting `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` to 0 (i.e. removes it altogether).
2. Sort rankings are interpreted modulo 100, so 40, 140, 240, ... are treated as the same value (see comments).
3. `Quick Access` and `This PC` appear to be configured differently and I haven't figured out where they are defined yet, so I am using large sort rankings to ensure 3rd party entries come after.
4. You might need to run Registry Editor as administrator (use either method [here](https://superuser.com/a/968225/207006)) and [take ownership](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/13811) of the values before you can modify them. It works for me only running as Admin without having to take ownership, but I'll leave this here for reference.

Comment: Disclaimers aren't necessary

Comment: Yeah it seems kinda like a meme to say it at this point.

Comment: I will add to this that MEGAsync on my machine uses the has {D387DC59-8DDF-456E-8A57-xxxxxxxxxxxx}, for those that want to re-order that as well.

Comment: This was great - thanks! I found that if you set the values over 100 then it loops back round to the top of the list. 50 put things between "This PC" and "Network" for me - anything more than 60 put it after "Network". This is on Win 11... in case that helps anyone else.

Comment: A few missing details.  It can be quite challenging to locate the specific CLSID.  Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace and take note of the application hash, then find it by appending it to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}. From there you might need to add a new DWORD 32-bit value for "SortOrderIndex"

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in current Windows 11 (23H2) with new File Explorer. Changing the SortOrderIndex seems to have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Not enough rep to comment, sorry! This is building on Elaskanator's answer above.

`{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-xxxxxxxxxxx}` -> Libraries.

You can enable/disable this through the UI as well.

By default SortOrderIndex (dword) key doesn't exist for this one, but you can add it to maneuver it in the list. (eg I set mine to 0 to make it appear over "This PC" and Dropbox.

Quick Access, This PC, and Network do not have an entry in this list. Additionally, Quick Access doesn't seem to care about sort order.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer how to remove Quick Access (another [question](https://superuser.com/a/1409261/207006) entirely). And thanks for contributing, the above bot comment is very disparaging (I've flagged it as unhelpful - I remember the pain too). Now if only I could stop "3D Objects" under This PC from regenerating every Windows Update...

Comment: Don't worry about not having enough rep to comment, I think pretty much everyone agrees that this limitation is unnecessary and it doesn't prevent or stop spamming or trolling

Answer (score 1):

So to fix this problem I used [WinAero (free software)](https://winaero.com/).
After opening it, look for

> "Navigation Pane" -> "Default Items".

Uncheck `/` check some items and they will appear in that specific order.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on Windows 11, found my SID, changed the `SortOrderIndex` and restarted explorer - no changes. Also restarted the computer without any success.

Does anyone know if this still applies to Windows 11? Or any other approach needed?

Edit:
Seems like the only way to re-order is to rename the items as they are sorted in alphabetical order.