# Vim cannot detect openssh installation on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh, vim, openssh

Vim/Gvim is unable to detect my OpenSSH installation in windows10. How do I make vim detect the installed ssh?
I want to edit files over sftp using vim, which I cannot do at this moment. I can use ssh from the command prompt without any problems.

Running the following from a command prompt shows ssh is installed and is in the path

```
C:\Windows\System32>where ssh
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

C:\Windows\System32>where sftp
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sftp.exe

echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;[snip];C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;[snip]
```

However if I submit the following from vim (or gvim)

```
:!where ssh
```

I get

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (where ssh)
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

However running the following from vim shows the PATH is seen correctly by vim

```
:!set
```

Also browsing into C:\Windows\System32\ using netrw shows that OpenSSH is not listed as one of the directories there.

Running gvim as an administrator makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Vim is normally distributed as a 32-bit application, which means it runs under the [WoW64 emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64), where `C:\Windows\System32` is mapped to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, and the original System32 folder becomes `C:\Windows\Sysnative`.  Since [Microsoft currently installs OpenSSH only to the 64-bit System32 folder](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1504), it becomes invisible to 32-bit applications by default.

There are several different workarounds:

1. Add `C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH` to your PATH, so that it is accessible when running 32-bit programs;
2. Install a 64-bit build of Vim, bypassing the WoW64 redirect mechanism entirely; or
3. Create a directory symbolic link, so that the OpenSSH folder can be accessed under WoW64.

### Option 1: Install 64-bit Vim

The [vim.org download page](https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) says:

> If you want a signed version you can get a build from
> [vim-win32-installer](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases)
> It supports many interfaces, such as Perl, Tcl, Lua, Python and Ruby. **There are also 64bit versions** which only run on 64 bit MS-Windows and use a lot more memory, but is compatible with 64 bit plugins.
> You can also get a nightly build from there with the most recent improvements, with a small risk that something is broken.

You can get 64-bit Vim builds at: https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases

### Option 2: Add C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH to your PATH

See [How to add a folder to 'Path' environment variable in Windows 10 (with screenshots)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho) on StackOverflow.

### Option 3: Create a directory symbolic link under the SysWOW64 folder

This requires administrative privileges.  This is the most comprehensive solution, but may potentially cause problems with a future software update if Microsoft ever decides to fix the [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1504) in their OpenSSH package.

1. Open an administrative command prompt.  PowerShell (<kbd>Win+X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>) or [CMD](https://superuser.com/questions/968214/open-cmd-as-admin-with-windowsr-shortcut) will both work.
2. Run the following command:

```powershell
cmd /c mklink /D %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OpenSSH ..\System32\OpenSSH
```

#### Removing the symlink

To remove the symlink that you just created, you can run the following command:

```powershell
cmd /c rmdir %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OpenSSH
```

The important thing here is to use a command that will delete *only* the symlink itself.  Directory symlinks are not commonly used on Windows, and many programs will attempt to remove it by deleting the entire contents of the target folder.