# How to enable OpenDNS on one Windows 10 user only?

Tags: windows-10, dns, web-filtering

I have two users on my Windows 10 machine, one for myself and one for a child. I wish to set up some sort of task scheduler that will only connect to OpenDNS when my child's user is logged in, but will not be enabled when I am logged in. This is to allow me to block Facebook and Twitter on my child's user but not on mine.

How can I do this?

If this is not possible, can you recommend alternative methods to enabling web filtering on one windows user only?

Comment: When you set up the account for the child, did you choose the "Child" option? That would enable you to set website restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to blocking access to these sites through DNS, could be on the the operating system (Windows 10), or Browser level. The keyword to research is "Parental Control".

For the OS level, you can edit the [hosts](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) file opening [cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/968214/open-cmd-as-admin-with-windowsr-shortcut) with admin right and then type

```
notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

# Block Facebook
127.0.0.1       facebook.com
127.0.0.1       twitter.com
```

This isn't automated yet,but could be with some scripts.

Windows 10 itself offers parental control on a user level as described [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-block-inappropriate-websites-windows-10). In general you add the child account as a family member and can then define content restrictions. Antivirus programs often also have content blocking capability.

But in the end this all depends on the tech savviness of the kid. There are always ways to get around these kind of blockades.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple batch files to set the DNS server like so (my batch scripting is very rusty, there might be mistakes)

```
@echo off
if '%username%' == 'administrator' goto adminSetup
if '%username%' == 'son' goto sonSetup

goto ender

:adminSetup
netsh interface ip set dns "Name of Network" <Primary DNS IP>
netsh interface ip set dns "Name of Network" <Secondary DNS IP> index=2

goto ender

:sonSetup
netsh interface ip set dns "Name of Network" <Primary DNS IP>
netsh interface ip set dns "Name of Network" <Secondary DNS IP> index=2

:ender
exit
```

One containing your settings, one containing the openDNS settings for your son.

Then

- run `taskschd.msc` under an administrator account to start Task Scheduler.
- Create a new task folder or right click an existing one and chose *Create Task*.
- In the *General* tab, give the task a *Name* and enable *Run with highest privileges*.
- Under the *Triggers* tab, click *New*.
- In the *Begin the task* dropdown, select *At log on*. Make sure you have *Enabled* on.
- Under the *Actions* tab, click *New*.
- From the dropdown, chose *Start a program*. Then click the *Browse* button and navigate to the correct batch file.
- Click *Ok*. Click *Ok* again.